# Ansible: Messed up variables?

Tags: python, ansible

```
TASK [deploy_aker : Copy SSH key L2 users to host] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [test.florius.com]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "checksum": "cfcc6cdae818178456c4eca8e89ebce0c14ec91b", "msg": "Destination directory /home/[u'test1', u'test2', u'test3', u'test4']/.ssh does not exist"}
```

It tries to create a directory called `[u'test1', u'test2', u'test3', u'test4']`, however it should ofcourse best `/home/test1/` etc...
What am I doing wrong:

```
- name: Copy SSH key L2 users to host
  copy:
    src: files/L2.pub
    dest: /home/{{ l2_users }}/.ssh/authorized_keys
    mode: 600
```

I tried quoting my variable like `'{{ l2_users }}'` but then my directory just got quoted... 
What am I doing wrong, and how do I correct this?

I use `{{ l2_users }}` to add the users to a host and that works fine, but copying the file is messed up...

Thank you!

EDIT: My VARS file, just in case it might provide a clue:

```
---
l2_users:
  - test1
  - test2
  - test3
  - test4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop the list and copy key into home directory

Example:

```
- name: Copy SSH key L2 users to host
  copy:
    src: files/L2.pub
    dest: /home/{{ item }}/.ssh/authorized_keys
    mode: 600
  with_items: l2_users
```

But instead of copying key, I would suggest to use `authorized_key` module for best practice.

```
- name: Set authorized key took from file
  authorized_key:
    user: '{{ item }}'
    state: present
    key: "{{ lookup('file', '/path/of/id_rsa.pub') }}"
  with_items: l2_users
```

Comment: bare variables in `with_items` are not supported long ago...

Comment: So it doesn't work because I didn't loop it, and it made the separate values 1 variable?

And I will be using `authorized_keys` for that then, I wasn't aware of it's existence! Ansible has too many modules haha!